# iOS 7 tableview no longer auto scrolling when keybaord appears

Tags: uitableview, sdk, keyboard, scroll, ios7

I am working on an app which I have just released an iOS7 version of. In the app I have a table view that contains text feilds in each cell. The problem is that when I tab to edit a feild that is near the bottom of the screen the keyboard appears and I cant see what I'm typing. I fixed this in iOS6 by simple listening for the event of the keybaord appearing and changing the size of the tableview so that it no longer extended to the bottom of the screen, but instead only reached to the top of they keyboar. The table view would then "automatically" scroll so that the cell was visable. This worked fine in iOS6 but as soon as I made the switch to iOS7 this no longer works... it no longer "automatically scrolls" when I change the size of the table. Does anyone know if there is a property that I need to set or something to "re-enable" this functionality?

Comment: I have the same problem. Works for iOS 6, but not iOS 7. Have anybody found a solution to this problem?